# AngularJS - input radio default to null or blank

Tags: angularjs

This works fine, except I cannot initialize var1 as "" or null. I'd like the "All" item to be selected, but it seems to not register as "All" via ng-value. Once the value is clicked, it seems to work.

```
angular.module('myApp', []);  
angular.module('myApp').controller('test_controller1', function($scope) {
  $scope.colors = [ "red", "green", "blue" ];
  $scope.var1 = "";
});
```

...

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="var1" ng-value="" id="all"> <label for="all">All</label> 
<input type="radio" ng-model="var1" ng-value="'red'" id="red_id"> <label for="red_id">red</label> 
<input type="radio" ng-model="var1" ng-value="'green'" id="green_id"> <label for="green_id">green</label> 
<input type="radio" ng-model="var1" ng-value="'blue'" id="blue_id"> <label for="blue_id">blue</label>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/UyaKv2UFpWOyoMvpuDE9?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Just realized ng-value="''" works the way I'd like. Nevermind.